# Understanding the intercept in an unadjusted logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients, intercept

I have performed an unadjusted logistic regression using weights (obtained via genetic matching) as below. I am using the `survey` package to make working with the weights easier:

```r
fit <- svyglm(outcome ~ group, design = match_df_svy, 
        family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"))  

    ShowRegTable(fit)

                exp(coef) [confint] p     
    (Intercept) 0.11 [0.09, 0.14]   <0.001
    groupTRUE   1.14 [0.88, 1.46]    0.323
```

`group` represents my intervention. Am I interpreting this correctly that since this is an unadjusted regression, the intercept in this case would represent the odds ratio when `group = FALSE`?

This doesn't seem to be the case by just looking at the incidence of the outcome in both groups:

```r
          group     outcomeFALSE      outcomeTRUE     se.outcomeFALSE     se.outcomeTRUE
    FALSE FALSE        0.8980632       0.1019368         0.009810129        0.009810129
    TRUE   TRUE        0.8858308       0.1141692         0.007180766        0.007180766
```

A rough calculation of the odds ratio from this 2x2 table results in similar point estimates and CIs:

```r
epitools::oddsratio(c(898, 101, 885, 114))
    $data
              Outcome
    Predictor  Disease1 Disease2 Total
      Exposed1      898      101   999
      Exposed2      885      114   999
      Total        1783      215  1998
    
    $measure
              odds ratio with 95% C.I.
    Predictor  estimate     lower    upper
      Exposed1 1.000000        NA       NA
      Exposed2 1.144994 0.8623838 1.522286
    
    $p.value
              two-sided
    Predictor  midp.exact fisher.exact chi.square
      Exposed1         NA           NA         NA
      Exposed2  0.3492472    0.3863462  0.3479743
    
    $correction
    [1] FALSE
    
    attr(,"method")
    [1] "median-unbiased estimate & mid-p exact CI"
```

I assume therefore that I am interpreting what the intercept actually means incorrectly and am just looking for some basic guidance.

Comment: The [intercept](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/92903/930) can not be interpreted as an odds-ratio like other regression coefficients. See also [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34638/930) for more information.